# How do I position and resize text in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website, but for some odd reason I can't move or resize the text. I do not want to use CSS because it is really hard for me to understand.
Here is an example of what i'm talking about in the image:

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: @RST_Plays Add your codes in the question, image alone will help us tell where in code should be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`CSS` is a very important part of front-end developing, so you shouldn't be afraid to use and learn it. You can start to link your `css` to your `html` like this :

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css">
  <!-- Or specify the directory C:/User/... 
but it's more efficient if you only specify the file created into a folder so if you move that folder changes will apply along with the html-->
</head>
```

Then open the `created css` and use these rules : (`Only {}`)

```
Resizing Text:

p(or the part of html that you are using){
   font-size: 40px;
}

Move Text : 
(Consider that you are moving the object FROM the direction
to the opposite one: 
example left:80px means that it will be 80px away from the left side.

p{
   position:absolute; 
   left:80px; 
   top:20px;
}
```

Comment: for every rule you have to go to head like: align: center (go down) font.size.... remember to put the ";" after every rule, it is very important

Answer (score 0):

I know three ways to change the size of the text, which are:
Use css
Or
Make changes using the Style tag inside the Head tag
Or
Using the Style tag inside the desired used tag, such as:

```html
<p Style="font-size:10px;">hello</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the font tag

```
<font size="3">I want the size to be small.</font>
```